# PLSQL Read Input

Tags: sql

Why is this not working?:

```
Declare
type tablica is table of varchar2(30)
index by binary_integer;
tab tablica;
i integer :=0;
n integer :=0;
inp integer:='&inp';
one varchar(20);

Begin
While n<3 Loop

n:=n+1;
tab(n):='&one';

End Loop;

(....)
```

It should read 3times input from keyboard and put it into table of char - and it read only 1 time :/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use & in PL/SQL? The substitution is for SQL. This will work:

```
Declare
  type tablica is table of varchar2(30) index by binary_integer;
  tab tablica;
  i integer :=0;
  n integer :=0;
 --inp integer:='&inp';
 one varchar(20);
Begin
 While n<3 Loop
  n:=n+1;

  If n = 1 Then
     tab(n):='one';
  elsif
    n = 2 Then
     tab(n):='two';
  Else
     tab(n):='three';
  End if;

   dbms_output.put_line(n||chr(9)||tab(n));
 End Loop;
End;
/
```

Here's some good example of what you may want:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/pl_sql_while_loop.htm

Comment: Hello, I need to put a few times information's into tab(n), so I use the &, but the Loop is running, and it asks me only 1 time for input and put it in all tab() - I thought: Step1: Loop -> put my input from &inp into tab(1),  Step2: Loop -> overwrite &inp with put my new input and put it into tab(2) and so on, but once I put something into &inp it wont change

Comment: @user2107202 - In PL/SQL you create procedure/function with parameters, not with &. Then you run the procedure and put values in place of parameters. With your code the procedure will run once and ask you enter value once. Then it will return value you entered 3 times. This is what you wrote. Put the real data and requirements in your example.

Comment: Hello, exactly this happens. Has maybe someone an example how to make a Loop to put dynamically input into table variables?

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP hasn't posted a procedure or a function but an anonymous PL/SQL block, which is perfectly capable of accepting substitution parameters. Whilst not necessarily the best way of going about it this is a simple way to accept user input.

Comment: @Ben - I'm not arguing, yes, it is possible to use & in PL/SQL. But in real world you do not usually do such things.

Comment: @user2107202 - I added more to my example. I hope I understood your correctly - not sure...

Comment: The Loop is not the Problem. 

I'm not sure what to use to put input to an array inside the Loop ( the & is not working like I want):

I need:

Loop

Step 1 -> put something into tab(1)
Step 2 -> put something into tab(2)
Step n -> put something into tab(n)

End Loop


and 2nd what I need:

how to do this in SQL (if it's possible):
int array[4];
array[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

Thank's all